# both launch and async running in parallel?

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine

I've already tried using coroutine (launch and async) many times. both of them running in parallel but why many people say launch is'nt?
In this example i used 3 coroutines each of them has 1 second delay.

This is async. It takes 1 second to finish.

```
DefaultDispatcher-worker-3 is running
DefaultDispatcher-worker-3 is running
DefaultDispatcher-worker-3 is running
async1 finished
async2 finished
async3 finished
1109 ms
```

This is launch. It also takes 1 second to finish.

```
DefaultDispatcher-worker-2 is running
DefaultDispatcher-worker-2 is running
DefaultDispatcher-worker-2 is running
launch1 finished
launch2 finished
launch3 finished
1102 ms
```

Comment: `launch` and `async` are essentially the same but the latter returns a result and there are some differences when it comes to exception handling.

Comment: @Pawel thank you, I will learn more about it.

Answer (score 1):

Using both `launch` and `async` can run tasks in parallel. The difference is that `launch` returns a `Job` whereas `async` gives you a `Deferred` which is effectively a `Job` with a result.

Therefore if you're looking to use the results of two tasks, `launch` isn't a good choice.

Comment: thank for your advice. I will learn more about it, much appreciated